# In CIL, why is BGE equal to CLT.UN followed by BRFALSE?

Tags: c#, .net, cil

In the CLI specifications ([ECMA-335](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-335.pdf), page 329), and also [on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.bge%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), it is stated that the CIL opcode **bge** is equivalent to performing a **clt.un** followed by a **brfalse**.

This baffles me. I don't understand why the equivalent is the unordered **clt.un**, and not the regular **clt**. Especially considering there is also a **bge.un**, which does not state an equivalent set of instructions. I whould have expected **bge** to be equivalent to [**clt**, **brfalse**], and **bge.un** to be equivalent to [**clt.un**, **brfalse**].

Is this an error in the specifications or am I missing something?

Comment: It is a bit clumsily written, explained better in the next paragraph.  "un" here means *unordered*, not *unsigned*.  It applies only to floating point operands and only matters if one of them is NaN.  Clt.un is "overloaded" for floating point, they are never unsigned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That PDF states:

> The effect of a *`bge target`* instruction is identical to:
>
> - If stack operands are integers, then `clt` followed by a `brfalse` target
> - If stack operands are floating-point, then `clt.un` followed by a `brfalse` target

Comment: It does indeed conflict with itself. I'm going to accept this answer, but I still wonder if this is an error in the specifications.